# Android application cannot be updated on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

One of our application in production cannot be updated, on some devices. There are no changes in the AndroidManifest.xml, other then version name and code.

This is the case:

- Version of the application on the http://play.google.com is 2.6.1 (latest version).
- Version on the application on the device is 2.4.0 (old version).
- Application on Google Play cannot be updated. There is no "UPDATE" button, only "OPEN", like there is no latest version.
- Once the application is uninstalled and then reinstalled, it is on the latest version.

How can this happen?
Did anyone had any similar experiences?

best regards,
Ivan

Comment: I think that is just Delay on Google Play System.

Comment: Did you changed the min SDK version or introduced a new requirement? Can be something missing in the device.

Comment: I had same issue with my app. in some of device with latest play service this kind of issue occur.

Comment: @WindSekirun: not a delay, the issues exists a few months now.

Comment: @Sandro: no changes in manifest, issue exists across multiple devices/OS versions.